# Push-based notifications with CoAP protocole in java

Tags: java, notifications, push, coap, californium

I am willing to use CoAP protocol to implement a push-based messaging system. In other words, one server observing some client and pushes notifications with some specific rate. I am using [the java implementation of CoAP](https://github.com/eclipse/californium). However I did not find any existing solution to build the above system.
Does anybody have already implemented such a push-based model with CoAP in Java?